# PermissionError when trying to rename a file on OneDrive

Tags: python, file, file-permissions, onedrive, permissionerror

When I run my code that encrypts a file, I get the following error:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/depen/OneDrive/Documents/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1 >(2).png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
read
encrypting
encrypted
encrypted file saved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\depen\OneDrive\Documents\python\timer\encrypt.py", line 93, in <module>
    encrypt(fpath)
  File "c:\Users\depen\OneDrive\Documents\python\timer\encrypt.py", line 67, in encrypt
    os.rename(file_fpath, file_fpath + ".encrypted")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/depen/OneDrive/Documents/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1 (2).png' -> 'C:/Users/depen/OneDrive/Documents/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1 (2).png.encrypted'
```

Here is my code:

```py
fernet = AES(key)

def encrypt(file_path):
    #start a timer
    start = time.time()

    def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size= 52428800):
        while True:
            data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
            data = fernet.encrypt(randbytes(16), piece, randbytes(16))
            currenttime = time.time()
            print(currenttime - start)
            with open (file_path + ".enc", "ab") as f:
                f.write(data)
                f.close()
    
    with open("filenames.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(file_path + "\n")
        file.close()
    #end the timer
    end = time.time()
    print ("Time taken to encrypt   `: " + str(end - start))
    os.remove(file_path)
```

The code does encrypt the file but dose not add a .encrypted to the end of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because  you are working on onedrive directory . Onedrive is trying to sync the file so once you create the file , he's  trying to upload the file.

Try to execute your code from another directory that onedrive is not using

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/depen/OneDrive/Documents/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1 (2).png' -> 'C:/Users/depen/OneDrive/Documents/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1 (2).png.encrypted'
```

Comment: I have ended one drive and i ran it and it gave me this error<
    Path(file_fpath).write_bytes(encrypted_file)
  File "C:\Users\depen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1143, in write_bytes      
    with self.open(mode='wb') as f:
  File "C:\Users\depen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1119, in open
    return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "C:\\Users\\depen\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Dep's Notebook.url"

Comment: also i want to be able to encrypt files in onedrive aswell